# AngularJs same model for main window and iframe window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I am trying to open a new iframe window upon clicking some link on the main window. However, I would like to use the same model i.e if the data changes in main window, it should be reflected in iframe and vice versa. Main window UI will have couple fields whereas iFrame window will have all the fields.

I am pretty new to angujar world, is it doable? If yes, any suggestions?

Comment: Don't think this is really an AngularJS specific problem rather you need to look at how to communicate with the iFrame via javascript if you can achieve this then the angular portion should be relatively moot.

Comment: As you are new to AngularJS, have you considered an [`ng-include`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) directive as an alternative to the iframe? It can hold separate html template and logic to the parent page but the two are connected through angular's scope (parent and root scope)

Comment: Why are you using and iFrame?

Comment: @shaunhusain Agreed, this isn't very specific to Angular, but just wanted to see if using Angular might help since I am already using Angular.

Comment: @LcLk That might be a good solution. Basically I would like two windows to be on two different screens and hence something like modal window won't work. If you have any dummy examples, that would be awesome!

Comment: @Fresheyeball I would like users be able to drag windows on different screens but still use the same model.

Comment: @PremShestha, could you elaborate, maybe with a diagram. What do you mean by screens, windows and modals in this context?

Comment: @LcLk Let's say I have four tabs and with some data on each tab. Now there is going to be a link on the bottom of each tab upon clicking which a new window should open with the data in that tab and more which is editable. The new window should be drag-able. When the data on the new window is changed, it should be reflected in the main window.

The solution does't have to be iFrame or anything specific but that's what came in my mind as they need to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of multiple templates on an angularjs page is trivial using the [`ngInclude`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) directive.

And the [`ngCompile`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) example shows a draggable div.

It should be easy enough to place an ng-include inside the draggable element. 
You can also use the same controller for the whole page, including the `ngInclude`, removing the need for sharing data through a `service` or `factory`.

**Edit:**

I have created a simple [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcLk/3DUy6/2/) showing a single template.
As you can see the input fields are in the main page.
Then a div with an `ng-include` directive loads an inline template (in practice these will be full separate html pages).

As the included template doesn't have a separate controller (which is possible, and commonly used), it is within the parent controller's scope. Thus the template has access to the `name.first` and `name.last` variables.

You will learn more about these by going through the [angularjs tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)

Comment: I am not sure how ng-include will help to keep track of changes within different windows. For example, first window has field called FirstName, clicking on edit will open new window with FirstName and LastName, how to reflect this change in first window?

I am thinking to storing values into localStorage and listen to the value change of that localStorage so that I could update UI in either main window or new window when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. The new iFrame is running in a different context. Also there is security restrictions between the iFrame and the parent if the are from different domains.

What you can do is to implement a messaging system between the parent and the iframe using html5 postmessage. You can watch for changes on your scope in the main window notify the child of the changes and update the scope of the child.