# Angularjs with iframes and/or multiple windows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, share

As usual, there are lists and item views in our application. Now, there's a requirement of showing both the list and details of one item (another huge list) at the same time. This is easily done, but for people using multiple monitors, it'd really nice to have a possibility to show the details optionally in a new window.

For those using a single monitor, would an `iframe` make sense? I know, it's more complicated than using just a controller, but it'd more directly correspond to using a window, wouldn't it?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22365261/581205), sharing the data is forbidden. According to the first paragraph of the `Window.postMessage()` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), it's only allowed in some cases, *including mine*. Do I understand it right? Can I share my services across multiple windows/iframes?

*If so, how?* `window.parent.and_what_now???`. Can I refer to a service from the parent window in a controller running in the child?

If not, I'd like to expose my services via proxies, does it make sense?

Comment: Why not just have two separate urls, and allow the user to open the other data in a new tab in the other window? If you need to communicate between windows, use sockets, or local storage.

Comment: @MattWay Separate URLs, no problem. But I don't want two communicating applications each one doing all the work. There's a lot of data (it's an administration application) to be shown and process and *to keep up to date*, so I want to share as much as possible.  Local storage allows strings only and converting them to and from objects sounds bad when it gets big. Moreover, local storage is limited to a few megabytes.

Comment: Why would the item view have to do "all the work"? If you are working with large lists, can't you retrieve it in chunks rather than a huge list? Can you preprocess on a backend? Also feels like premature optimisation.

Comment: @MattWay I don't want to work with chunks as it's complicated, when you want to show the data sorted and filtered according to different criteria which get changed often; the shown columns change too (think Excel user). Moreover, I don't want to bother the server with any work which may get done on the client. Nor should the slave window client fetch things the master already has.

Comment: @MattWay It's no premature optimization, as some lists have a few thousand items and we're just starting.
For some users (sitting on good desktop computers), there'll be much more (incremental fetching is planned). 
I made the decision to avoid chunking as it's on optimization which is difficult given varying filtering and sorting criteria and which puts more stress on the server. So far it works well.